# JQuery .load() into variable or hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pulling data from a section of one page into another in order to build a menu.  I need to pull the data into a hidden element or variable as right now I end up with a duplicate menu.  My dynamic fly out and the static `<ul><li>`'s.  The menu is built of of these.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.ms-quickLaunch').replaceWith('<div id="hierarchy" style="border:solid 1px white; width:0px; visibility:hidden"></div>');
    });

$(function(){
            $('#hierarchy').load('http://wwcshare/icenter/Pages/wwcMenuContent.aspx #menuContent',
                function(){
                    $(this).menu({
                        autoShow: true,
                        content: $(this).html(),
                        backLink: false,
                        crumbDefaultText: ' '
                    });
                });         
            });
</script>
```

This works except that my menu is no longer getting placed where it belongs.  It is at the top of the page instead in side the `#hierarchy div`.

---

Here is my ALTERNATE ATTEMPT based on one of the answer's:

```
$(function(){    
            $.get('http://wwcshare/icenter/Pages/wwcMenuContent.aspx', function(data){ // grab content from another page
                contentIwant = data.find("#menuContent");
                $('#hierarchy').menu({
                    autoShow: true,
                    content: contentIwant,
                    backLink: false,
                    crumbDefaultText: ' '
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a $.get() would suit your purposes better than a $.load()

using $.get() you can process the data before loading it into the page

Comment: Except that a `$.get()` cannot get a specific portion of a site, correct?

Comment: not automatically, but that's a small hurdle.   `data.find("#element")`

Comment: they're both shortcuts for $.ajax, $.load just goes one step past what you're wanting imho, better to stop one step short and manually go the last step.  Manually undoing a step is harder.

Comment: stupid question but where do you generally do the `find()`.  My get looks like this:  `$.get('http://wwcshare/icenter/Pages/wwcMenuContent.aspx', function(data){`  Do I try it there or later when I try and use `data`?

Comment: the `.find()` is done in the callback.  So something like.  `contentYouWant = data.find("#id");` some more processing as needed then `$("#hierarchy").menu({
                        autoShow: true,
                        content: contentYouWant,
                        backLink: false,
                        crumbDefaultText: ' '
                    });`  all within the callback

Comment: Please see  my edit, I must be doing something wrong because it is not working at all now

Comment: see if `content = $('#menucontent',data).html();` helps

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter whether the element you are loading into is hidden or not. If it exists in the DOM then you can load into it.

Either make sure the element is hidden via CSS first:

```
#element{display:none;}
```

or

Hide the element with jQuery when you load the content into it:

```
$('#holder').hide().load('mypage.php');
```

Hope this helps you man!

W.