# Import portion of file using $.get

Tags: jquery, variables, load, find

I want to import the contents of a html file and fill a textbox (input type:"text" value="") with the contents.

So far I've got:

```
$("a.clickable").click(function(event){
  $.get('site.html', function(data){
    $("input#textbox").val(data);
  });
});
```

This works just fine, but I only want to import a portion of the file specified by div id (or class), similar to what would happen if i used .load, like so:

```
$('#textbox').load('site.html #someid')
```

or (if it was possible):

```
 $.load('site.html #someid', function(data){...
```

I suppose that I can't store the imported text as a variable using .load, so that is out of the question (right!?!). I was thinking that maybe by using .find('#someid') I could get the wanted part from the html file. There is a similar thread on this:

[JQuery .load() into variable or hidden element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260400/jquery-load-into-variable-or-hidden-element)

...but no mater what I can't seem to get it to work!

Comment: The entire file always comes over. You can do whatever you like with it once it's here (for instance .load() only "loads" a selected part of it), but you definitely get it all.

Comment: You're on the right track. What did you try?

Comment: That `.load()` syntax you suggest is in fact supported by jQuery already :-)

Comment: @Pointy, it is? Simply replacing $.get by $.load in the above code doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @SLaks, I tried several variations and combinations of the above.
I tried something like:
 $.get('site.html', function(data){ 
                contentIwant = data.find("#someid");
                $('#textbox').val(contentIwant ...
 
That being from the example in the link.

Comment: Well it's supported but the problem is that `.load()` expects to work with elements that are **containers**.  @Hoff's answer is basically correct, though you may want the `.html()` of an element in your content and not its `.val()`.

Comment: You probably want `contentIwant.html()`

Comment: Could you elaborate on that SLanks? Where do I put that in?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('/your_url/', function(reply_string){
  // turn reply string into a jQuery object so you can look up elements and evaluate
  var retrieved_value = $(reply_string).find('#your_element').val()
  $('#textbox').val(retrieved_value)
})
```

not very elegant but should work...

Comment: Possibly you wan the `.html()` or `.text()` of "#your_element", especially if it's not an `<input>` field.

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean Pointy... Indeed the text is supposed to be inserted in a <input> field and extracted from a html file

Comment: @Hoff (and others): So, I got it running, however I had to place the entire output of $.get in a div using '.html' and from there run '.find' and '.text()'. Seemingly '.find' and '.text' does not work "on the fly" for some reason, so the script I have to use isn't beautiful, but it works... Anyway, thanks for the help and if you come up with other tips and tricks let me know! I'll be checking in!

Answer (score 0):

I found that trying to use `$(layout).find("#fragment-id")` on HTML retrieved via `$.get()` would only give me an empty object. Instead, as @Matte commented on another answer, I added the raw HTML to a `div` I created with jQuery. I could then use `find()`, get the fragment I wanted, and store this in a variable. I was able to  append the variable to my target, or use it later.

```
var $template;
$.get("layout.html", function( layout ) {
  $template = $("<div></div>").html( layout ).find("#fragment-id");

  $target.append( $template );
}
```

The code above returns the complete fragment as a jQuery object, which suited my purpose. If you wanted just the plain inner html from the fragment, you'd need to use `.find("#fragment-id").html()`