# How to know when page has been loaded with references completely after post in jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am using the below to get the whole page when I submit a form, now the page takes time to load as it calls its CSS and JavaScript.
I need to show that data is still being loaded in that page, before anybody uses it again.
I would like to use a modal popup with loading and once the page is loaded completely I will close the popup
How canI achieve that?

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
    url:  $url,
    data: "post=" +  post,
    //   data: form_data,
    success: function(data) {
        if(data!=""){
            $('body').html(data);
            ...
```

additonal data:

I have two frames in a window. in the right side frame my page has links which when clicked will post certain data in hidden fields and get the whole right side page with the changed data. now my right side page has links such as

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="abc.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>

<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

These files take time to be retrieved form server once the page is loaded by  $('body').html(data); I want these files to be loaded and then let the user do his work

Answer (score 1):

Since you are applying `load` to the entire `body` element, any modal popup display prior to this will be removed ready for the new content.

Therefore, I would suggest [loading your content into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260400/jquery-load-into-variable-or-hidden-element) first by using `$.get()`:

```
var content;
$.get($url, "post=" + post, function(data){
    content = data;
});
```

This means you can have a loading icon displayed during this process, then load the content into the `body` which will remove the loading icon:

```
//show modal popup here    
$.get($url, "post=" + post, function(data){
    var content;
    content = data;
    if (content!=null){
       $("body").html(content);
     }
});
```

My syntax might not be quite right as I haven't been able to test this, but it should give you an idea of the logic which would work.

Comment: the issue is the whole page gets loaded again so as soon as the post data is returned the modal closes automatically and the page starts loading.

Comment: I think you need to explain this a little better. Are you submitting the form, reloading the page, and expecting the modal to show while the page reloads it self ?

Comment: I have two frames in a window. in the right side frame my page has links which when clicked will post certain data in hidden fields and get the whole right side page with the changed data. now my right side page has links such as    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="abc.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
       
        <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>                                                                These files take time to be retrieved form server once the page is loaded by  $('body').html(data);

Comment: @Curt - How will that work with the async nature of $.get ? Won't the if statement always be false, as the content will not be loaded when the if statement executes ? Actually, since the variable is defined at the top, will it ever be null ?

Comment: @adeneo Good point! I've made another improvement so that all code is in the callback function of `$.get`

Comment: Thanks curt tried your example and have understood your logic,but am still getting same problem

Answer (score 1):

Use ajaxStart and ajaxEnd to show the loading message.

```
$("#myjaxloader").bind("ajaxStart", function(){
    $(this).show();
}).bind("ajaxStop", function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Add the message and image in myajaxloader

You can use [blockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) if you want more blocking features.

Comment: I have tried this and the issue is that ajax finishes but the js files that are linked in the head are still to be brought from the server so ajaxstop is before all my files are loaded

Answer (score 0):

```
$(form).on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // to stop the page from reloading
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",
        url:  $url,
        data: "post=" +  post,  //use form.serialize to send the whole form
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(modal).show();
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        if(data!=""){ $('body').html(data); }
    )).always(function() {
        $(modal).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the onload event of the loaded frame. If both your frames are on the same domain, you can do something like this:

navigation window:

```
$.post(url, data).then(
    function() { // success handler
        window.errorTimer = setTimeout(showErrorPopup, 10);
    }, function() { // error handler
        showErrorPopup();
    }
);
showLoadingPopup();
```

content window:

```
$(function() { // runs after everything is loaded
    window.top.otherFrame.clearTimeout(window.top.otherFrame.errorTimer);
    window.top.otherFrame.hideLoadingPopup.call(window.top.otherFrame);
});
```