# jQuery Load Without Appending to Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery's load function to get template data from external html files. In most cases I prefer to storage the data in a variable and append it when I need to later on. For example, I may end up cloning the node several times, or appending other data to it etc etc. The point is I need to be able to load an element from an external file, but not append it to an existing document.

What I am doing now is simple:

```
var storage = document.createElement('div');
$(storage).load('somehtmlfile.html #sampleTemplateDiv');
```

But its annoying to have to remove the html from inside the storage div every single time. It would be nice if I could do something similar without having to append to a redundant container div and I could just have the data from the html file waiting nicely in the storage variable. Is this possible?

A non-jquery solution would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery .load() into variable or hidden element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260400/jquery-load-into-variable-or-hidden-element)

Comment: The answer in the duplicate question does not seem to suffice. It suggests using a data.find function in a get call, but in my attempts the data.find function does not seem to be available.

Comment: Please read my comment before voting to close for duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to use .ajax instead of .load and to temporarily store the data in the storage div, the extract it and return the element. I am using this inside an external function as well, so it was appropriate to make this a synchronous call...unfortunately or I wouldn't be able to properly return the element.

```
var ret = null;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        var storage = document.createElement('div');
        storage.innerHTML = data;
        var template = $(storage).find('#' + id);
        if(template.length > 0) ret = template[0];
    }
});
return ret;
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you load it into a jQuery object that is not appended to the DOM?
e.g.

```
var data = $( '<div id="loaded-content" />' ).load( url );
```

You later when you want to use it:

```
$( '#my-container' ).html( data.html() );
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by loading a JSON object which contains the data, like so:
(you could also point the URL to a server-scripted file that reads the URL parameters and outputs a JSON object)

Example:

```
//JQUERY:
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "path/to/template.json",
  success: function(data) {
    var storage = data.template.html;
    // do something here
  }
});

//JSON FILE:
{
  "template":
  {
    "html":"<div ...></div>",
    "some_var":"some_value"
  }
}
```

---

Another way, you could just load the HTML file with parameters... ex: change the url to: `url: "path/to/my_template.html?id=some_div"` or use load() with the URL with params in it.

Then in each template file just insert a script to read the variable and rewrite the document with the element requested.

Code:

```
//query.js
function getQueryString() {
  var q = {}
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0; i<vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    q[pair[0]]=pair[1];
  }
  return q;
}
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $q = getQueryString();
    if ($q.id) {
      document.write($($q.id).html());
    }
  });

//template html files
//head section
<script type="text/javascript" src="query.js"></script>
```

I havent tested this but I think it should work...

You'll need to put that script in each template file.

Comment: Is there no way to do this same sort of thing but instead load an html file and pick the element by id like .load does?

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML file? @ryandlf

Comment: Yes. I simply store template data in separate html files so it doesn't clutter up the dom and my display html.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to append .load to document ready. It loads the php functional script without the need for an element.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // code
}).load('url/to/file.php');
```

Hope this helps!